# Font Awesome Icons Not Showing Up on my webpage I made using Bootstrap4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am making a **webpage using Bootstrap4(CDN)** and I intend to use **FontAwesome icons** for my social media links. However on opening the page I see some **blue boxes** instead of the icons and **they are functional**. I just need the icons to be displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the necessary snippets :
1.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

2.

```
<ul class="social-icons">

                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/avirup.dey.921" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.quora.com/Avirup-Dey-5" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-quora"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.github.com/AvirupJU" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto: avirupdeyju@outlook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

[Here is what I see...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7WC2.jpg)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ygsutqLp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `v4.*.*` of font-awesome **the prefix `class` of invoking your desired icon is `fa` not `fab`**.

> `fab` and `fas` are for the brand and solid styles in `v5.*.*` and also, `fa` is deprecated in this version. You can read more about it [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

so you need to make a change in your script just like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="social-icons">
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/avirup.dey.921" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.quora.com/Avirup-Dey-5" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-quora"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.github.com/AvirupJU" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto: avirupdeyju@outlook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** You can upgrade your current version from [here](https://fontawesome.com/?utm_source=v4_homepage&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=fa5_released&utm_content=banner).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the CDN you have. Request a Kit by creating an account on fontawesome website. They will give you something like this: `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc188b5fd5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` or you can simply use this.
For displaying the envelope you need to change from `<i class="fab fa-envelope"></i>` to `<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

<ul class="social-icons">
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/avirup.dey.921" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.quora.com/Avirup-Dey-5" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-quora"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.github.com/AvirupJU" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto: avirupdeyju@outlook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```