# Font Awesome Icon not loading properly

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I have a GitHub Pages site up and I'm using some Font Awesome icons at the bottom. Three of them load, but the last one isn't.

How the stylesheet is linked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

How the icons are placed:

```
 <a class="btn_social"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
 <a class="btn_social"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a class="btn_social"><i class="fab fa-envelope"></i></a>
  <a class="btn_social"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

I've tried replacing `fa` with `fab` and `fal` but im not sure what these mean or what they do.

Comment: i think `fab` refers to font awesome brand icons, while `fal` refers to the "light" version of the icon, example - https://fontawesome.com/v5.5.0/icons/comments?style=light

Comment: @SMAKSS yes this answers it. I guess i needed to use ```fas```

Comment: I think this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864587/font-awesome-icons-not-showing-up-on-my-webpage-i-made-using-bootstrap4)

Comment: Yea, you need to use `fas` so it will look like this at the end: `<a class="btn_social"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>`

Answer (score 1):

I have used your key.

### My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <a class="btn_social"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
</body>

</html>
```

### Output

[image]

### btn_social

I do not have the properties of this.  If you need more feedback, please share your code (full).

I hope that the community helps you.